# How to massively mark files as moved with Bazaar?

Tags: version-control, dvcs, bazaar, tortoisebzr

I have **moved** 3 files **from the top folder working copy** under bazaar into a new directory `Project`.
Bazaar show me this screen.
[image: Bzr overview after moving files]

Now, I want to **mark every file as moved**. It is possible to do this one file by one file  - by selecting the missing one, the new one, and clicking mark as moved.
[image: Mark as move example for one file]

BUT it is **not possible to massively do this for all files**.
The screens capture are just an example, in my real project, I have ~40 files.
Any idea to do this for all files ?

---

**EDIT with the accepted answer :**
in TBZR > Run command and use : `bzr mv --auto`
[image: Accepted answer]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using `bzr mv --auto` from the command-line to auto-detect moved files. This works best if you haven't also changed the contents of the files.

You could also avoid this situation in the future by using `bzr mv <src> <dest>` to move the files, which also notifies Bazaar that they have moved.

Comment: Along the same lines, you might be able to use a shell script to do `bzr mv --after <src> <dest>`

Comment: Is this `bzr mv --auto` option exist somewhere in Tortoizebzr ?

Comment: @TridenT try "All commands" from Bazaar Explorer. I'm not sure how this menu named in Tortoise (maybe Run command).

Comment: Ok, it works perfectly with command line or with the 'All commands' from TBZR. Many thx you all !!!